# I keep getting unexpected outputs in this program that changes date format

Tags: c, date

I am trying to write a program that gets in the input a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY and changes the format to DD-MM-YYYY without using string functions in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>



typedef struct {
    char day[3];
    char month[3];
    char year[5];
} date;

int main(){
    char input[11];
    date DATE ;
    DATE.day[3] = '\0';
    DATE.month[3] = '\0';
    DATE.year[5] = '\0';  
    printf("%s\n", DATE.day);


    int i = 0;


    // saisie de date
    printf("enter date in the format DD/MM/YYYY\n");
    scanf("%s", &input);
    
    //fill in 

    // fill in  day
    for (int j = 0; j<2; j++){
        DATE.day[j] = input[i];
        i++;
        
    }
    i++;

    // fill in  month
    for (int j = 0; j<2; j++){
        DATE.month[j] = input[i];
        i++;
    }
    i++;

    // fill in  year
    for (int j = 0; j<4; j++){
        DATE.year[j] = input[i];
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s-%s-%s", DATE.day,DATE.month,DATE.year);

    
    return 0;
}
```

I figured that the problem has to do with how I initialized the strings. However it still doesn't work.

Comment: `DATE.day[3] = '\0';` you mean `DATE.day[2] = '\0';` - same with the others.

Comment: seems a bit overly complicated .. just scan the entire input string and replace `'/'` with `'-'`

Comment: As well as @500`s observation, I suggest that using loops is overcomplicating things... ``DATE.day[0] = input[0]; DATE.day[1] = input[1]; DATE.month[0] = input[3]; DATE.month[1] = input[4]; DATE.year[0] = input[6]; DATE.month[1] = input[7];`` is simpler and clearer (with comments)

Comment: If the date is indeed entered in the specified format, then it seems the only thing the program needs to do is convert two '/' characters at known positions into '-' characters.  That's just two assignment statements.  You're making this *much* too complicated.  Or if you want complicated, then spend it on validating the format of the input.

Comment: @yano it is part of a bigger program, i just copied the part i have a problem with..

Comment: So your real question is "How to parse the day, month, and year from a DD/MM/YYYY input?" because you need to use them elsewhere? JohnBollinger's solution is simpler than my suggestion anyway. You can use [`strtok`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), but if the format is always DD/MM/YYYY that's too complicated IMO also. Toss up whether you want to use loops or hardcode everything. Could also use `memcpy`. Lots of options.

Comment: but as the first comment points out, you're currently overwriting the bounds of your arrays, so you need to fix that before you do anything else with them.

Comment: Before addressing the "parsing", there is no validation of `scanf()` returning EOF, and no restriction preventing the user entering an empty string or one of more than 10 characters (buffer overflow)... All bets are off...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that if you had compiler warnings set on, you received warnings about the array values your program was setting was out of bounds.  Keep in mind for any array that is set to a specific size (e.g. "3"), the highest index value for the array is the size value minus one (e.g. "2").

With that, I refactored the code as noted in the following listing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char day[3];
    char month[3];
    char year[5];
} date;

int main()
{
    char input[11];
    date DATE ;
    DATE.day[2] = '\0';         /* Fixed the index on these arrays */
    DATE.month[2] = '\0';
    DATE.year[4] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", DATE.day);

    int i = 0;

    // saisie de date
    printf("enter date in the format DD/MM/YYYY\n");
    scanf("%s", input);         /* Corrected the input to reference the character array pointer name - does not require the ampersand */

    //fill in

    // fill in  day
    for (int j = 0; j<2; j++)
    {
        DATE.day[j] = input[i];
        i++;
    }
    i++;

    // fill in  month
    for (int j = 0; j<2; j++)
    {
        DATE.month[j] = input[i];
        i++;
    }
    i++;

    // fill in  year
    for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
    {
        DATE.year[j] = input[i];
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s-%s-%s", DATE.day,DATE.month,DATE.year);


    return 0;
}
```

Note the correction in the index values.  Also, FYI, when using scanf and entering a character array (e.g. a string), the variable name does not include the ampersand.  the name of the array references the pointer to the array.

Having made those tweaks, following is some sample output at the terminal.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/GetDate/bin/Release$ ./GetDate 

enter date in the format DD/MM/YYYY
11/04/1955
11-04-1955
```

Try out those corrections and see if it meets the spirit of your project.